# magento1 ajax select data

Tags: magento-1.9

I have file file controller

```
public function informationAction(){
    $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    $id = (int)$data['courseId'];
    $modelCourse = Mage::getModel('course/courses')->load($id);
    $this->_redirect('course/manage/courses');
    return;   
}
```

I want use ajax

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j("#information-part").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var courseId = $j('#courseId').attr('value');

    $j.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "JSON",
        url: "http://hungnguyen-magento.local/course/manage/information",
        data: {
            courseId : courseId
        },
        success: function(response){
            var html = '';
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

How i can select data from controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
public function informationAction(){
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        $id = (int)$data['courseId'];
        $modelCourse = Mage::getModel('course/courses')->load($id);
        $dataCourse = $modelCourse->getData();
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(json_encode($dataCourse));
        return;   
    }
```

Ajax

```
<script>
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j("#information-part").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var courseId = $j('#courseId').attr('value');

        $j.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "JSON",
            url: "http://hungnguyen-magento.local/course/manage/information",
            data: {
                courseId : courseId
            },
            success: function(response){
                alert(html);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thank you devidas

Answer (score 0):

Ypu mean, You need to pass data from controller to ajax?
For that You need to set json as body in response in controller:

```
$this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
$this->getResponse()->setBody($json);
```

Then in ajax You have easy access to data from controller as `response` param.
But be sure that data You encode to json are fine.  Good idea is to prepare array with needed data and use `json_encode`